# Pyspark Dropfields from a struct based on a condition

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I currently have a dataframe transformation into json with the current schema:

```
contact_info: {
  email: 'asas@asas.com',
  phone: 12312312,
  email_2: 'asasa2$asas.com'
}
```

I currently build it using this script:

```
df = df.withColumn('contact_info', F.struct(
    F.col('Email').alias('email'),
    F.col('Phone').alias('phone'),
    F.col('Email_02').alias('email_2')))
```

But sometimes the email_2 is empty and what I want is remove the field email_2 from the structure just when this happens.
I tried different approaches and could not achieve this.

```
df = df.withColumn('contact_info', F.struct(
    F.col('Email').alias('email'),
    F.col('Phone').alias('phone'),
    F.when(cons_df['Email_02'] != '', F.col('Email_02').alias('email_2')).otherwise(df['Email_02'].dropFields('contact_info.Email_02'))))

F.when(df['Email_02'] != '', F.col('Email_02').alias('email_2')).otherwise(df['Email_02'].dropFields('contact_info.Email_02')),
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from Email_02#20: need struct type but got string
```

```
df = df.withColumn('contact_info', F.struct(
    F.col('Email').alias('email'),
    F.col('Phone').alias('phone'),
    F.when(cons_df['Email_02'] != '', F.col('Email_02').alias('email_2')).otherwise(lit(None)))

contact_info: {
  email: 'asas@asas.com',
  phone: 12312312,
  col3: ''
}
```

I don't know if it's possible or I am trying to do it in the wrong way, I did it back on pandas using lambda functions and conditional statements

```
def contact_info(vals):
    val = {}
    email = None if 'nan' in str(vals['Email']) else str(vals['Email'])
    phone = None if 'nan' in str(vals['Phone']) else str(vals['Phone']).split('.')[0]
    email_2 = None if 'nan' in str(vals['Email_02']) else str(vals['Email_02'])

    val.update({'email': email})
    val.update({'phone': phone})
    if email_2:
        val.update({'email_2': email_2})

    return val

df['contact_info'] = dataframe[['Email', 'Phone', 'Email_02']].apply(contact_info, axis=1)
```

The end result in case Email_2 is empty should be:

```
contact_info: {
  email: 'asas@asas.com',
  phone: 12312312
}
```

**Edit2:**
I have to add, that the issue is on `ignoreNullFields, False`, as there are other fields that when Null, I do not want to avoid being stored.

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').option('ignoreNullFields',False).json('s3://mylocation/')
```

Comment: I'm wondering about why you want this.  In most cases, it's easier to check for a field being empty than to check for a field being absent.

Comment: Basically, I will use this to create a elasticsearch index and populate a Website database, but for cases like email or phone, even if it empty, it still will show email: None or something like that, but If I do not have Email_2 ( or even 3, 4 or 5 ) I do not want a redundancy for the user of showing email : None email_2: None , etc etc, and want to avoid the UI taking care of this cases by creating a clean index.

Comment: In case of struct, the schema of the whole column will be the same, it can't be different based on row values. For your use case, you can use MapType instead. I can add answer if you're ok with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check on `df.columns` and **dynamically** include the required columns in `struct` and use `to_json` function to create a json string.

**`Example:`**

**`1.If email exist:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------+--------+---------------+
#|        email|   phone|        email_2|
#+-------------+--------+---------------+
#|asas@asas.com|12312312|asasa2$asas.com|
#+-------------+--------+---------------+

#define the required columns
req_cols = ['email','phone','email_2']

#using for loop shorthand and check the columns included only the columns that are part of dataframe columns
df.withColumn("contact_info", to_json(struct([col(f) for f in req_cols if f in df.columns]))).show(10,False)
#+-------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|email        |phone   |email_2        |contact_info                                                            |
#+-------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|asas@asas.com|12312312|asasa2$asas.com|{"email":"asas@asas.com","phone":"12312312","email_2":"asasa2$asas.com"}|
#+-------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**`2.if email_2 doesn't exist:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------+--------+
#|        email|   phone|
#+-------------+--------+
#|asas@asas.com|12312312|
#+-------------+--------+
req_cols = ['email','phone','email_2']

df.withColumn("contact_info", to_json(struct([col(f) for f in req_cols if f in df.columns]))).show(10,False)
#+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
#|email        |phone   |contact_info                                |
#+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
#|asas@asas.com|12312312|{"email":"asas@asas.com","phone":"12312312"}|
#+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yeah, your example works perfectly, but I realize that I was missing 2 things, 1st is that I already convert everything to a json when I store the end result of the dataframe, and secondly is that I deactivate the IgnoreNullFields on storing, but in those particular fields I want to remove them.